# Zip together files that have filenames that match recursively through directories

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, find, zip

Consider a file system like so:

```
folderA
   - one.png
   - two.png
   - three.png

folderB
   - one.png
   - two.png
   - three.png

folderC
   - one.png
   - two.png
   - three.png
```

I want to zip together all of the .png's that match `one.png` into a .zip file named `one.zip`. Important to note that it should only search filenames specifically and not look inside of files, because code that is generating these .png's exists and I don't want to be matching anything that isn't an actual .png.

I tried search around but with the keywords I know to use, I get a lot of results about searching *within* a .zip file.

I'm on OSX Mojave. Would appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Adhi

Comment: Bonus points for a script that will make zips for all of `one`, `two` and `three` where I can specify the actual filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can go crazy and put all the `one.png` files into `one.zip`, all the `two.png` files into `two.zip`, etc:

```
for file in $( find -name \*.png | sed 's:.*/::' | sort -u ); do
    zip $(basename $file .png).zip $( find -name $file )
done
```

Comment: `for file in $(...); do ...; done` and unquoted variables are anit-patterns.

Comment: I really don't care about patterns and anti-patterns.  I can annoy even more people by using back-quotes instead of `$(...)`.

Comment: You understand they're anti-patterns because they're dangerous to use though, right? I doubt if anyone's annoyed by you using them or backquotes though. The questions, answers, and comments posted on this forum aren't just for you, they're for everyone reading the posts now and in future. So whether you care about anti-patterns or not, if there are issues with a posted answer then it's good to have them pointed out so others reading that answer in future have a better understanding of the implications of using that answer.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not well versed in bash, could you tell me the risks of using Jack's solution given the anti pattern?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These for more info.

Comment: If someone puts spaces in filenames, fire him.

Comment: I'm getting "find: illegal option -- n" - is it possible that I have the wrong version or software?

Comment: OK -- your MacOS problem.  Instead of `\*.png`, use `'*.png'`.

Comment: There's no functional difference between `\*.png` and `'*.png'` - in both cases you're protecting `*` from shell expansion. The real problem is that most `find`s require a starting directory as the first argument. Just change `find -name` to `find . -name`. wrt spaces in file names - I've never deliberately created one but my directories contain several created by tools, downloaded from emails, web sites, etc. Pretending they don't exist will bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

```
base='one'
mapfile -t files < <(find . -name "${base}.png")
zip "${base}.zip" "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: The OP is using macOS Mojave and the version of `bash` that ships with it (3.2.57(1)-release) does not contain the `mapfile` built-in command.

Comment: @user3439894 I'm using macOS High Sierra (the one before Mojave) and the version of bash I'm running (4.4.12(1)-release) does contain mapfile so I expect it's also available to the OP even if she has to install it.

Comment: macOS High Sierra ships with `bash` 3.2.57(1)-release and not everyone upgrades `bash` like you obviously did. The point I'm trying to make is you've given an answer that does not work on macOS unless one upgrades to a version of `bash` that contains the `mapfile` built-in command and as such you should state in your answer that upgrading `bash` is going to be required. You should also probably include how to do that as well.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, so your solution *almost* works. The issue is that it preserves the folder structure surrounding the files.

For example, when I write the script and run it, i get a zip that opens and looks like this:

```
folderA
   -one.png
folderB
   -one.png
folderC
   -one.png
```

I would like for it to come out to a folder that just has the .png's and nothing else.